Laravel Horizon: One concurrent job per user
I am looking for a way that would allow me to only allow one job to run for each user at a time.
That could be through Job tags or something else. All I want is to specify the tag User:1 and based on that horizon would run only one job for the user at a time. As soon as the job finishes it would allow that user to process another job.
This assumes you have more than one process for the horizon queue. Currently my queue only has 1 process which does the job but I am looking for ways to optimize this by having one process per user essentially.
Is this possible?

You can use the WithoutOverlapping middleware and specify the user id as a key. Note that by default scheduling an overlapping job will trigger retry of the job and you can quickly exhaust the retries. So if you employ this strategy, you should either automatically reject the new job from the queue (e.g. not allow to schedule one), or don't use a fixed retry count, but retryUnitl instead. And if you go for not accepting another job, you can use a unique key instead.
They you can configure the auto-scaling of Horizon.
